# eclipse regular expression file search not working

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to search for any file in my eclipse workspace that contains the word "trim", but not ".trim", using the eclipse's Search -> File option.  On the eclipse search window, I put the following in the "Containing Text" input box and put a checked mark on the "Regular Expression" check box.

```
((?<!\.)\btrim\b)+
```

But the search yields 0 result, which I'm sure is wrong because I know one of the file in my eclipse workspace contains this text: "where uuid = trim('&4')";

I tried the regular expression on https://regex101.com/ site and it seems to work fine.

Any idea what I did wrong in eclipse?

Comment: It works fine for me in the current Eclipse. Make sure also the file name pattern matches. By the way,  `((?<!\.)\btrim\b)+` can be simplified to `(?<!\.)\btrim\b` since the group cannot be repeated more than once (`\btrim\b\btrim\b` is not possible).

Comment: odd.  All the sudden, it is working now.